# What is the time complexity(Big O) of Cassandra operations?

Tags: cassandra, key, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

Assume there is only one node with R rows. What is the theoretical time complexity of basic Cassandra operations?

More specifically, I want to know:

1. `key = item`. I assume it to be `O(log(R))` is it right?
2. `key > item`, i.e. slice. Will C* fetch all R rows to judge if the condition is met, which results in `O(R)`? What about ordered rows?
3. `key > 10 AND key < 12`. Will C* first select all that matches `key > 10` and then filter with `key < 12`? Or C* will combine them into a single condition for query?

Answer (score 0):

You don't clarify if you mean reads or wites, although it seem you are talking about read operations.   The read path in Cassandra is highly optimized with diffent read caches, bloom filters and different compaction strategies (STCS, LTCS, TWCS) for how the data is structured on disk. Data is written on disk in one or more SSTables and the presence of tombstones degrades read performance, sometimes significantly.

The Cassandra architecture is designed to provide linear scaleability as data volumes grow.  The premise of having just a single node would be the major limiting factor in read latency as the number of rows R becomes large.